# Why do I get a Segmentation Fault when calling getImageBlob with PHP and Imagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, jpeg, imagick

I have a JPEG image blob string in memory, and load it into an Imagick object. Then I resize it to a thumbnail, compress it, etc. When I write the new thumbnail to disk, it works fine and I can see the file. When I try to get the Blob String from Imagick, it always throws a Segmentation Fault. I never need to write these files to disk. I get them from a URL, resize them, then push the image blob string to an Amazon S3 key/value bucket.

Why does it throw a Segemntation Fault, and how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
$photo['Data'] = file_get_contents('image_url'); // this works
$Image = new Imagick();
$Image->readImageBlob($photo['Data']);
$Image->scaleImage( 160, 0 );
$Image->setImageCompression( Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG );
$Image->setImageCompressionQuality( 60 );
$Image->setImageUnits( imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH );
$Image->setImageResolution( 72, 72 );
$Image->stripImage();
$Image->writeImage('test.jpg'); // this produces a good thumbnail
$thumb['data'] = $Image->getImageBlob; // this throws a segmentation fault
```

**Imagick Version Information**

**Output from `sudo yum info php-pecl-imagick`**

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
Name        : php-pecl-imagick
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.1.0
Release     : 0.2.RC1.6.amzn1
Size        : 418 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
URL         : http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
License     : PHP
Description : imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the
            : ImageMagick API.
            : This extension requires ImageMagick version 6.2.4+ and PHP 5.1.3+.
            : 
            : IMPORTANT: Version 2.x API is not compatible with earlier versions.
```

Comment: What version of Imagick are you using? stuff like that isn't mean to segfault, and ought to be fixed.

Comment: I'm using Imagick installed on Amazon AWS via `yum install php-pecl-imagick`. It's version `ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2014-05-12 Q16` according to `identify -version`.

Comment: Could you post the version output from `yum info php-pecl-imagick` please?

Comment: Added to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix.

`getImageBlob` is a PHP function and needs to have parentheses. Calling `$Image->getImageBlob()` works, while calling `$Image->getImageBlob`results in a segmentation fault.